# Jboss 7.1.1.Final - Get stats of servers in a cluster?

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing

I am doing jboss 7.1.1 clustering with standalone-ha.xml.

Is there an admin interface to modcluster or something that can get me some cluster statistics like number of servers active, error states, load, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On httpd configuration you can add a admin page handler (http://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.2.0/html/native.config.html#SetHandlermod_cluster-manager).

This page will give you an overview ov mod_cluster statistics (registered nodes, active session, jboss reported load and others).

By default the configuration, as it should, limit the by the ip range who can access the page.